# Display the text in the same line in Django templates

Tags: django

I just started with Django. I rendering the text coming from the database. Even though it is in `<li>` tag the text is rendering in the new line. I also tried giving class `col-md-2` but no use. Thanks in advance.

```
<section class="resume-section p-3 p-lg-5 d-flex align-items-center" id="skills">
<div class="w-100">
  <h2 class="mb-3">Skills</h2>
    {% for  skill in skills.all %}
  <ul class="list-inline dev-icons">
    <li class="list-inline-item">
       <h5> &emsp;{{skill}} </h5>
    </li>
</ul>
  {%endfor%}
</div>
```

---

views.py

```
skills = Skills.objects
return render(request,'home.html',{'jobs':jobs,'projects':projects, 'skills':skills})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop creates new `ul` on each step, so move it inside the `ul` tag:

```
  <ul class="list-inline dev-icons">
    {% for  skill in skills.all %}
        <li class="list-inline-item">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using your for loop the wrong way. Use this instead:

```
<ul class="list-inline dev-icons">
  {% for  skill in skills.all %}
    <li class="list-inline-item">
      <h5> {{skill}} </h5>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Also, why not retrieve the skills in your view instead?

```
skills = Skills.objects.all
return render(request,'home.html',{'jobs':jobs,'projects':projects, 'skills':skills})
```

You can then use `{% for  skill in skills %}`.